# HTML UL list 4X2

Tags: html, css

i need to create UL list in html 4X2

something like this

item1 | item2 | item3 | item 4

item5 | item6 | item 7| item 8

Is that possible to do with ul list?

I know how to create klasic licst.. like

```
<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the float CSS property to achieve this.

A JSFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLHqC/1/).

```
li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just show `li` element inline and make two separate lists:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
li { display:inline; }
```

If you want more control, you can put `inline-block` and set width, margin, etc.

[JS Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A4TU9/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5y3SB/)**

**css**

```
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add max-width to UL to width that is not more than four ite